# Access other fields in getter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to make it that every time I get `subtotal`, it adds 2 other fields, `productTotal`, and `tax`.

Here's my code:

```
const cost = new mongoose.Schema({
    payment: {
        productTotal: Number,
        tax: Number,
        subtotal: Number, // (productTotal + tax)
    }
});


const Cost = mongoose.model('Cost', cost);
```

How can I add 2 feilds from the same schema when getting a different field?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that in mongoose by creating a virtual field for `subtotal`. The mongoose reference documents this pretty well here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/virtuals.html.

**EDIT:**
The code snippet below shows how you can define a cost schema that has a `subtotal` virtual on the payment subdocument:

```
const PaymentSchema = new Schema({
  productTotal: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  tax: { type: Number, default: 0 },
});

PaymentSchema.virtual('subtotal').get(function () { return this.productTotal + this.tax; });

const CostSchema = new Schema({
  payment: PaymentSchema,
});
```

From the above snippet you can get the subtotal from a Cost document instance via `cost.payment.subtotal`.

Comment: Thanks!!! Would I be able to access nested docs like this:
`cost.virtual('payment.subtotal').get(function () {
 return this.payment.productTotal + this.payment.tax;
});`

Comment: Also, virtuals has a limitation of not being accessible by `find`. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: @Jessica I've updated the answer to show how virtuals can be used with a nested document. To my knowledge, if you want to use the subtotal field with a `find` query you'll need to save the field to the database upon document insertion.

Comment: Got it. So how can I create a getter when saving the field to the db?

Comment: @Jessica what I mean is that `subtotal` can be calculated before saving the cost to the db. That way, you can read its value like any property after retrieval from MongoDB. Hope that clarifies a little?

Comment: Yes, but is there a way of having it automatically calculated, this way anytime one value is changed, subtotal will automatically update?

Comment: @Jessica you can add a [middleware](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre) to detect if the field has changed and recalculate. Something like this should do:
```CostSchema.pre('save', function () { if (this.modifiedPaths().includes('payment')) { // calculation goes here.
}});```